# AOSP: "warning string 'gsm alphabet default_charset' has no default translation"

Tags: android, translation, android-resources, android-source

When I'm run in my Android Project the make-process, I received an Error message. "warning string 'gsm alphabet default_charset' has no default translation".

This just happens in this setting. In the configuration setting, I select in the lunch set "mini_emulator_x86_64-userdebug".

To start this process I typed in "make -j8".

Has anyone the same error?

Best Regards Georg

[image]

```
note:out/target/product/mini-emulator--86_64/obj/APPS/CalculatorGoogle_intermediates/package.apk may be a plain executable, not an archive
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/CalculatorGoogle_intermediates/package.apk or
       out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/CalculatorGoogle_intermediates/package.apk.zip, and cannot find out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/CalculatorGoogle_intermediates/package.apk.ZIP, period.
target Prebuilt: CalendarGooglePrebuilt (out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/CalendarGooglePrebuilt_intermediates/package.apk)
 End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
 a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
 latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
 the last disk(s) of this archive.
note:  out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/CalendarGooglePrebuilt_intermediates/package.apk may be a plain executable, not an archive
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/CalendarGooglePrebuilt_intermediates/package.apk or
       out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/CalendarGooglePrebuilt_intermediates/package.apk.zip, and cannot find out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/CalendarGooglePrebuilt_intermediates/package.apk.ZIP, period.
frameworks/rs/driver/runtime/arch/generic.c:641:11: warning: 'rsClamp' is deprecated: Use clamp() instead. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   p.r = rsClamp(p.r, (short)0, (short)255);^
frameworks/rs/driver/runtime/arch/generic.c:20:59: note: 'rsClamp' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
extern short __attribute__((overloadable, always_inline)) rsClamp(short amount, short low, short high);
^
frameworks/rs/driver/runtime/arch/generic.c:642:11: warning: 'rsClamp' is deprecated: Use clamp() instead. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   p.g = rsClamp(p.g, (short)0, (short)255);
         ^
frameworks/rs/driver/runtime/arch/generic.c:20:59: note: 'rsClamp' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
extern short __attribute__((overloadable, always_inline)) rsClamp(short amount, short low, short high);
                                                         ^
frameworks/rs/driver/runtime/arch/generic.c:643:11: warning: 'rsClamp' is deprecated: Use clamp() instead. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   p.b = rsClamp(p.b, (short)0, (short)255);
         ^
frameworks/rs/driver/runtime/arch/generic.c:20:59: note: 'rsClamp' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
extern short __attribute__((overloadable, always_inline)) rsClamp(short amount, short low, short high);
                                                         ^
target Prebuilt: Chrome_32 (out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/Chrome_intermediates/package.apk)
target Prebuilt: CloudPrint2 (out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/CloudPrint2_intermediates/package.apk)
3 warnings generated.
target Prebuilt: Drive (out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/Drive_intermediates/package.apk)
Unable to open 'out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/CalculatorGoogle_intermediates/package.apk.unaligned' as zip archive
Unable to open 'out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/CalendarGooglePrebuilt_intermediates/package.apk.unaligned' as zip archive
Unable to open 'out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/Books_intermediates/package.apk.unaligned' as zip archive
make: *** [out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/Books_intermediates/package.apk] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/CalendarGooglePrebuilt_intermediates/package.apk] Error 1
make: *** [out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/CalculatorGoogle_intermediates/package.apk] Error 1
 End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
 a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
 latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
 the last disk(s) of this archive.
note:  out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/CloudPrint2_intermediates/package.apk may be a plain executable, not an archive
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/CloudPrint2_intermediates/package.apk or
       out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/CloudPrint2_intermediates/package.apk.zip, and cannot find out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/CloudPrint2_intermediates/package.apk.ZIP, period.
Unable to open 'out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/CloudPrint2_intermediates/package.apk.unaligned' as zip archive
make: *** [out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/CloudPrint2_intermediates/package.apk] Error 1
 End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
 a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
 latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
 the last disk(s) of this archive.
note:  out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/Drive_intermediates/package.apk may be a plain executable, not an archive
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/Drive_intermediates/package.apk or
       out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/Drive_intermediates/package.apk.zip, and cannot find out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/Drive_intermediates/package.apk.ZIP, period.
Unable to open 'out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/Drive_intermediates/package.apk.unaligned' as zip archive
make: *** [out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/Drive_intermediates/package.apk] Error 1
 End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
 a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
 latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
 the last disk(s) of this archive.
note:  out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/Chrome_intermediates/package.apk may be a plain executable, not an archive
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/Chrome_intermediates/package.apk or
       out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/Chrome_intermediates/package.apk.zip, and cannot find out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/Chrome_intermediates/package.apk.ZIP, period.
```

```
Unable to open 'out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/Chrome_intermediates/package.apk.unaligned' as zip archive
make: *** [out/target/product/mini-emulator-x86_64/obj/APPS/Chrome_intermediates/package.apk] Error 1
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/ab_share_pack_holo_dark.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xhdpi/ab_share_pack_holo_dark.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/ab_share_pack_holo_light.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/ab_share_pack_holo_dark.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xhdpi/ab_share_pack_holo_light.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/arrow_down_float.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/arrow_up_float.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/btn_default_normal_disable.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-ldpi/btn_minus_default.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-ldpi/btn_minus_disable.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xhdpi/btn_minus_disable.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xhdpi/btn_minus_default.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/btn_minus_default.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/btn_minus_disable.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-ldpi/btn_minus_selected.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/btn_minus_selected.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xhdpi/btn_minus_selected.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/btn_plus_default.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-ldpi/btn_plus_default.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xhdpi/btn_plus_default.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-ldpi/btn_plus_disable.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/btn_plus_disable.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xhdpi/btn_plus_disable.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-ldpi/btn_plus_pressed.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-ldpi/btn_plus_selected.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xhdpi/btn_plus_pressed.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/btn_plus_pressed.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/btn_plus_selected.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xhdpi/btn_plus_selected.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/btn_search_dialog_default.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/btn_search_dialog_pressed.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/btn_search_dialog_selected.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/btn_star_big_on_disable.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/btn_zoom_up_disabled.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/btn_zoom_up_disabled_focused.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/btn_zoom_up_normal.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/btn_zoom_up_pressed.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/btn_zoom_up_selected.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/dialog_divider_horizontal_light.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/edit_query.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/edit_query.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/edit_query_background_pressed.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/edit_query_background_pressed.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/edit_query_background_selected.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/edit_query_background_selected.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xhdpi/edit_query.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/editbox_background_focus_yellow.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/editbox_background_normal.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/editbox_dropdown_background.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/focused_application_background_static.png: libpng warning: cHRM: invalid chromaticities
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_clear_disabled.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_clear_disabled.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_clear_normal.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_clear_disabled.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_commit.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_commit.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_contact_picture.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_delete.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_dialog_dialer.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_dialog_email.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_dialog_info.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_dialog_map.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_go.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_go.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_go.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_input_add.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_lockscreens_now_button.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-ldpi/ic_media_pause.png: libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'icc': 'RGB ': RGB color space not permitted on grayscale PNG
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_notification_overlay.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_popup_disk_full.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_popup_sync_1.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_popup_sync_2.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_popup_sync_3.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_popup_sync_4.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_popup_sync_5.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_popup_sync_6.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_search.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_search_category_default.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_voice_search.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/ime_qwerty.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_bar_left_end_confirm_gray.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_bar_left_end_confirm_green.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_bar_left_end_confirm_red.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_bar_left_end_confirm_yellow.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_bar_left_end_pressed.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_bar_right_end_confirm_gray.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_bar_right_end_confirm_green.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_bar_right_end_confirm_red.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_bar_right_end_confirm_yellow.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/jog_tab_bar_right_end_pressed.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/keyboard_popup_panel_trans_background.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/maps_google_logo.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/menu_separator.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/menu_separator.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/menuitem_background_focus.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/menuitem_background_pressed.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/menuitem_checkbox_on.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/panel_picture_frame_bg_focus_blue.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/panel_picture_frame_bg_normal.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/panel_picture_frame_bg_pressed_blue.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/perm_group_accessibility_features.png: libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'Photoshop ICC profile': 'GRAY': Gray color space not permitted on RGB PNG
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/perm_group_app_info.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/perm_group_audio_settings.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/perm_group_bluetooth.png: libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'Photoshop ICC profile': 'GRAY': Gray color space not permitted on RGB PNG
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/perm_group_bookmarks.png: libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'Photoshop ICC profile': 'GRAY': Gray color space not permitted on RGB PNG
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/perm_group_display.png: libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'Photoshop ICC profile': 'GRAY': Gray color space not permitted on RGB PNG
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/perm_group_device_alarms.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/perm_group_personal_info.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/perm_group_screenlock.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/perm_group_sync_settings.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/perm_group_system_clock.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/perm_group_system_tools.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/perm_group_voicemail.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/perm_group_wallpaper.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-ldpi/picture_emergency.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/picture_emergency.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xhdpi/picture_emergency.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/popup_bottom_medium.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/popup_bottom_medium.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/popup_center_medium.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/popup_center_medium.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/pressed_application_background_static.png: libpng warning: cHRM: invalid chromaticities
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/radiobutton_off_background.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/radiobutton_on_background.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/reticle.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/search_dropdown_background.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/search_plate.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xxhdpi/stat_notify_rssi_in_range.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xxhdpi/stat_sys_certificate_info.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/status_bar_background.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/status_bar_header_background.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/status_bar_item_background_normal.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/status_bar_item_background_normal.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/submenu_arrow_nofocus.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xxhdpi/switch_thumb_holo_light_v2.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/sym_app_on_sd_unavailable_icon.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/sym_contact_card.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-ldpi/tab_focus_bar_left.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-ldpi/tab_focus_bar_right.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-ldpi/tab_press_bar_left.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-ldpi/tab_press_bar_right.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/textfield_search_default.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/textfield_search_empty_default.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/textfield_search_empty_pressed.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/textfield_search_empty_selected.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/textfield_search_pressed.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/textfield_search_selected.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-ldpi/toast_frame.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
frameworks/base/core/res/res/mipmap-mdpi/sym_app_on_sd_unavailable_icon.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
warning: string 'gsm_alphabet_default_charset' has no default translation.

#### make failed to build some targets (02:16:36 (hh:mm:ss)) ####

georg@ubuntuOS:/repo$
```

Comment: this is a warning, not an error. If you're building with make -jX , the error is probably somewhere above  (since many threads are working in parallel ).
If you still need help, post the full log from the beginning.

Comment: I've tried to put in the whole log, since the beginning. I would be very happy if you can help me. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I've never seen that error, I'm not sure what's causing it. Seems that zips cannot be opened. Run an sudo apt-get apt-get update && sudo apt-get apt-get upgrade see if you maybe have some old zip binary. No other ideas sorry :/

Comment: Before I create this post I start the make - process with different Lunch settings. When I select another setting like e.g. "aosp_angler-userdebug" or like "aosp_arm64-eng" the process is working well, no warning occurred. Just with the mini_emulator_xxx.xxx I've got this warning. Maybe this could also help you.

One additional Information. During my search in the Internet I found similar warnings(Warning: string 'prediction_none' has no default translation - https://developer.android.com/studio/write/translations-editor.html#resources ). Can help this Information?

Comment: I start the sudo apt-get update && upgrade command with the result to received 86 additional updates are available with UA Infrastructure ESM.

Now I'm using the ubuntu 14.04 LTS all the latest updates are installed.

Comment: I removed all the entries from opengapps, now it still working perfectly. Thanks Rick Sanchez for your help!!

Comment: @RickSanchez: The same issue occured after removing any entries from opengapps. When I start the update and upgrade process with apt the failure didn't occured ageain! Cheers!

Can you mark this posting as solved? Because I cant...